# How to identify exclusive pairs/combinations

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a long list of pairs and would like to be able to uniquely identify pairs that are exclusive to each other. Is that possible in excel without VBA?

Pair

1. Abbot-Kinney <---exclusive
2. Kinney-Abbot <---exclusive
3. Dell-Sprint

How can I put a unique identifier in a separate column to show that the first two lines are exclusive to one another?

Comment: You are asking for "if there is same, but different sequence pair", is that correct? From what I understand, "exclusive to each other" means "A and B cannot happen simultaneously" which is not exhibited by your above example

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Maybe "unique combination" would have been a better phrase to use.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are after, however:

enter this array formula in `C15`

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(MID(TRIM(B15),FIND("-",TRIM(B15))+1,LEN(TRIM(B15)))&"-"&MID(TRIM(B15),1,FIND("-",TRIM(B15))-1),TRIM($B$15:$B$17),0)),"","exclusive")
```

and grag/copy it down:

[image]

`TRIM()` is used just in case if there are extra spaces lurking at the end of the text pairs.

Reminder: to enter an array formula, 
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you! This helps me identify the global list of exclusive pairs! I'm still trying to figure out how to identify each pair. For instance, Abbot-Kinney and Kinney-Abbot are pair A, let's say Dell-Sprint and Sprint-Dell are pair B.

Comment: How precisely do you want your pairs to be identified?